Space between deck beam & joist and deck wobbles side to side
My deck wobbles from side to side. So I started looking underneath the deck to check what the issue was and how to mitigate it. 
I noticed that the joists are attached to the beam using nails instead of Joist Hangers. I wanted to install joist hangers, but it looks like the beams are moving away from the joists and there is a noticeable space between them. The joists are level, but the beam is not. I am worried about the safety aspect and we avoid using the deck. I tried hammering the beam so that it would go in, but it wouldn't budge. 
I thought I would install a new beam (close to the exiting beam) that goes along underneath the joists and secure it using Hurricane Ties. The beam will be supported by new 4x4 posts and secured using Post Caps. Then I will install 2 rows of 2x6 blocks between the joists and secure them using joist hangers. I don't know if this is the right thing to do or if this is a viable long term solution.
What else can I do about it? Any other ideas? 
Looks like the beam is moving away at the bottom

As you can see the Joist is level

But the beam is not plum. Thanks for correcting me FreeMan.

EDIT1: Add more info based on comments
The deck is just sitting on the post and is not secured to the steel posts as commented by Huesmann. Even the bottom is just resting on the concrete block and I have no idea how deep the block goes in. Here are the pictures for top and bottom of the steel post. It looks like the post has moved because its not in the center of the bottom flange. And Aloysius Defenestrate, to answer your question, the post wobbles as well when I move the deck.
Top post section

Bottom post section

Side view of all posts


The joist in the pic is exactly off-level, like you want it to be so that water will run off the deck instead of puddling. Unfortunately, it appears to slope toward the house instead of away! In the 3rd pic, you don't show us if the beam is level or not. What you've shown is that it's not plumb (i.e. not vertical). That's likely due to some twisting (which wood does over time) - you would need to site along the beam to see if the twist is significant, we can't tell from this one pic.

I’m not convinced that your movement is caused by loose connections. Have you had someone move around on the deck while you stare at the posts?

Aaaand, there are vastly simpler ways of fixing the identified issues than throwing a bunch of lumber at it.

I see you have steel posts.  Your deck is basically just sitting on top of these posts and connected to the tiny flange on the post—if at all.  It doesn't look like there's much lateral connection the way there'd be on a wood post.  Do you know how far they're embedded in the ground?  What kind of foundation the columns have?

Will just replacing those steel posts with pressure treated 4X4 posts along with Simpson post cap and base help my deck?
